# Why do dates in a d3 chart show up as 1am in firefox in ubuntu but as the day and date in firefox in windows?

Tags: windows, firefox, date, ubuntu, d3.js

I have a bar chart with dates on the x-axis. I'm looking at the chart within firefox on windows and on ubuntu. I'm working off the line chart example from d3 : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

In windows the dates are in the following format "Thu 25" "Mon 29" etc.
On ubuntu every date is displayed as 1am.

This is the same across 3 machines I've checked on. I've also noticed the 1am on several examples on the d3 example page.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with d3 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with Firefox running under BST

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1196